# CSS pseudo-selector similar to :valid or :checked for select tags?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to find a non-JavaScript way of styling a `select` tag *if* it has a value that's been chosen.

For instance, if I have the following tag:

```
<select>
  <option value="">Select a widget...</option>
  <option value="1">Widget 1</option>
</select>
```

Is there a CSS selector I can use to tell when the value of that select tag isn't empty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [HTML5 Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element):

> The ***required*** attribute is a boolean attribute. When specified, ***the user will be required to select a value*** before submitting the form.
>
> **Constraint validation:** If the element has its ***required attribute specified***, and either none of the option elements in the select element's list of options have their selectedness set to true, ***or the only option*** element in the select element's list of options ***with its selectedness set to true is the placeholder label option***, then the element is suffering from being missing.
>
> If the ***value of the first option*** element in the select element's list of options (if any) ***is the empty string***, and that option element's parent node is the select element (and not an optgroup element), then ***that option is*** the select element's ***placeholder label option***.

<sup>emphasis is mine</sup>

The above statements imply that a `select` element with `required` attribute will become `valid` only when the user *selects* a value. Until then it will continue to be in `invalid` state.

---

The `:valid`, `:invalid` pseudo-selectors can themselves help to style a `select` element depending on whether a value has been *chosen* or not but it depends on a few factors. They are as follows:

- By *chosen*, you mean to check if a *valid* value has been chosen and not just any choice.
- The *invalid* or *empty* value (in this case "Select a widget...") has `value=""` and is the first option under the select element.
- The `select` element is a mandatory element - meaning, we can add the `required` attribute to it.

Based on your problem statement, I think your scenario satisfies all the aforementioned factors.

```css
select {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  outline: none;
}
select:valid {
  border: 2px solid green;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<select required>
  <option value="">Select a widget...</option>
  <option value="1">Widget 1</option>
</select>
```

The above snippet has been verified in IE10+ (including Edge), Chrome, Opera and Firefox.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I had misread the `:valid` docs, and thought they didn't apply to `select` inputs.  Thanks!